# should we create object of any class on class level or function level

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Which approach is better: I tried to find it on web, but I couldn't get a better answer.

1.

```
public class OtherClass
{

    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}  

public class TestClass
{

    OtherClass oClass = new OtherClass();

    public int Fun1()
    {
        return oClass.Add(1,2);
    }

    public int Fun2()
    {
        return oClass.Add(1, 2);
    }
}
```

2.

```
public class TestClass
{

    public int Fun1()
    {
        OtherClass oClass = new OtherClass();
        return oClass.Add(1, 2);

    }

    public int Fun2()
    {
        OtherClass oClass = new OtherClass();
        return oClass.Add(1, 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Fun1 and Fun2 are just vague. Do you have an actual scenario here? Is the Other class going to be used elsewhere in the TestClass

Comment: Impossible to say with such a contrived example

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what you are trying to test.

If you're testing the effects of a sequence of functions being executed on the same class instance then you might want to create a single instance (such as stress testing)

But otherwise I'd say it's always better to create a new instance of the class in each test function to ensure that the context of each test is predictable. If your test methods shared an instance of a class, and one test method fails and corrupts the state of the object under test, your subsequent test may fail for no other reason than the state of the object under test was corrupted by the previous failed test (it might appear the multiple tests are failing when in fact only one of the early ones is a true failure).

Comment: Sorry..if name of the class "test"..created some confusion..it is a normal class and not for test cases..will your answer be same in this case??

Comment: @himanshu_pareek_Yahoo: I'm sure you test your classes which are not named "Test", right?  Reducing scope and mutable state is a good thing.

Comment: @himanshu_pareek_Yahoo if you weren't asking about test cases, then the answer will be slightly different but in that case the question is poorly formulated. The answer depends a lot on your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the scenario, if the class is gonna be shared on multiple functions and there are no specific arguments needed to create an instance of that class then it's better of being at the class level.

Let's say you're using the **Fun1** and **Fun2** often, having the instance creation on the method will have instance creation overhead rather than it being at the class level having a single instance, or better yet, make it static or make it singleton if you're sure that it's going to be a single instance throughout the whole app.

One benefit of having it in the class level is if you're doing unit testing, you can make an interface like **IOtherClass** and Inject it in the constructor of **TestClass**.

It would look something like this.

```
public class OtherClass : IOtherClass
{

    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}  

public class TestClass
{

    IOtherClass oClass;

    public TestClass(IOtherClass _oClass)
    {
        oClass = _oClass;
    }

    public int Fun1()
    {
        return oClass.Add(1,2);
    }

    public int Fun2()
    {
        return oClass.Add(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're better off having it as a field in the class rather than declaring a new one in each method. The reason for this is simple, there won't be a line of code in each method declaring the variable meaning that if your declaration statement changes you will only have to change it in one place, not every method. Also it will make your code easier to read and add to because this line won't be duplicated everywhere.

Just remember if that field needs to be disposed your class should implement the IDisposable interface.

Comment: So LOC is a quality metric?  How about dealing with mutable state?  Does that factor into your assessment?